# PHP Warning while checking PHP version

Tags: php

Whenever I'm trying to check php version installed on my computer through cmd line, following warning message pop up

> PHP warning: unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:\xampp\php\ext\php_gd.dll'- The specified module could not be
>   found. in Unknown on line 0.

after warning it shows the php version.

Comment: Check if you have that file at specified path

Comment: Well.. does the `c:\xampp\php\ext\php_gd.dll` file actually exist? Otherwise you need to fix your `php.ini` used by php CLI.